# Table Row Odd/Even Reset

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am using this:

```
jQuery("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
jQuery("tr:even").css("background-color", "#ececec");
```

Just simply adding a  background color to alternating table rows, which works fine.  The problem is that if there are multiple tables in the same page, it just keeps iterating down each table instead of resetting for each table and starting new.  My `th` background color is the same color as my even rows So eventually it catches up and I have a `th` and  `tr` that are the same color so it looks like one big row.

How can I use those two lines of jquery, but make it start over for each table on the page if there are multiple tables?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing this with jQuery, rather than pure CSS?

Comment: Simply for cross browser compatibility.  Didn't think `nth-child` was fully supported, especially in older versions of IE.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: [IE9+ supports nth-child](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx).  jQuery has dropped support for anything older than IE9 in newer versions:  http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: FWIW, [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) doesn't have a detect for `nth-child`, but it does have a non-core detect for `last-child`, which is (probably) supported on the same browsers. You could use pure CSS for browsers that support it and a Modernizr detect to apply JS to browsers that don't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by selecting the tables, then finding the child rows:

```
jQuery("table").find("tr:odd").css("background-color","#f5f5f5");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/xgQ8Q/

[Vega's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16821904/901048) uses the same approach with fewer characters.

Comment: Perfect.  I'll accept as soon as it lets me, says 12 more minutes.

Comment: This still applies to all my tables. Can you just refer to a specific table using ID?

Comment: Figured it out, I could use an ID tag as such: jQuery("#myTable tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF3FB");

Answer (score 4):

Try using `table` in context like below,

```
jQuery("tr:odd", 'table').css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
jQuery("tr:even", 'table').css("background-color", "#ececec");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This worked as well, so I'll toss an upvote on it.  Just happened to get Blazemonger's answer first.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("table tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "red");
jQuery("table tr:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgQ8Q/5/

Comment: +1. Didn't occur to me that using `:nth-child(odd)` instead of `:odd` would give a different result.